# Correcting outliers using the standard deviation of a two-point different function?

Tags: noise, python

I recently read a research paper that discussed how to correct lightcurve data (flux vs. time) by using the method as explained below:

> We have considered as outliers in the datasets the individ- ual
>   measurements showing a point-to-point deviation in the two-point
>   dierence function of the light curve greater than 3 for the SC and
>   5 for the LC, where  is dened as the standard deviation of the
>   two-point dierence function.

SC and LC are just different versions of the data.

Could someone explain to me what they mean by the two-difference function and how they are using it to correct the time-series data?

*Edit:*

Here's the link to the paper. You can find this quote on page 3, section 3.1.
http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0382

Comment: You should add a link or reference to the paper if possible.

Comment: Here's the article. The quote I am referencing is on page 3, section 3.1: http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0382

Comment: Hard to say; the paper seems a bit esoteric for me. It sounds like it might be a two-point finite difference approximation to a first derivative, e.g. $y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]$.